# Cordova Override Android WebView Methods

Tags: cordova, webview, overriding

I am using Cordova 5.1.1 here.

Chromium.org changed some behaviour lately:
When you send a cordova app to the background, the navigator.geolocation will stop accessing the GPS sensor (i'm using high accuracy).

Chromium says "working as intended".

I got a hint tho - quote:

> There is a workaround.. override webview.getWindowVisibility and
>   onWindowVisibilityChanged to always report window being visible. That
>   effectively turns off the visibility optimizations, including pausing
>   geolocation.

I was trying to do so in my xxxxx.JAVA file, but failed.

Would one warmhearted soul pretty plz come up with an example (or even better: complete code) how to implement the needed overrides, where to put it -including the needed import directive(s)?

That would be awesome, since plain java coding is not realy on my agenda...

Thanks a ton!

Richard